# How to validate collections (list must not be empty rules) in Angular 2 Forms?

Tags: validation, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, primeng

So I am really stuck in building a form with validation. The idea is the following:

- This is a backend application
- The user needs to submit a form with credentials, a list of email addresses and a list of checksum values.

**What I want to validate is the following:**

- Username and password exists/not blank (got this to work)
- The list of email addresses is not empty
- The list of checksum values is not empty

**The Problem**

The problem is that I do not know how to validate the lists. I am using PrimeNG's PickList and DataTable components. I am also **currently using template driven forms** (answer doesn't need to be template driven). This is the HTML code for the respective sections:

**Picklist**

```
<p-pickList [source]="artifactoryList" [target]="artifactorySelectedList" [responsive]="true" [showSourceControls]="false"
                            [showTargetControls]="false" (onMoveToTarget)="addChecksums($event)" (onMovetoSource)="removeChecksums($event)">
... SOME TEMPLATING THAT GOES HERE BUT CAN'T SHOW ON STACKOVERFLOW PROPERLY ...
</p-pickList>
```

**DataTable**

```
                    <p-dataTable var="contact" [value]="model.contactList">
                        <p-column>
                            <template let-email="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                                <span>{{email}}</span>
                            </template>
                        </p-column>
                        <p-column styleClass="col-button">
                            <template let-email="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" (click)="removeContact(email)">
                            </template>
                        </p-column>
                    </p-dataTable>
```

**The Current Workaround**

The current workaround is to do nothing. So there is no validation on these two components. I checked everywhere for an answer but all examples only seem to use `input` html tags.

My current thinking is something like:

- I need to add the values of these lists to the value property of the ngForm object. So either

  - I am missing something obvious
  - I am meant to implement a missing interface (currently implementing `OnInit`)

**The Question**

The question is how to validate the backing arrays on both the Picklist and DataTable using the Angular 2 way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom validator for your custom list input.

the custom validator:

```
function requiredList(fromControl) {
  return fromControl.value && fromControl.value.length ? null : {
    requiredList: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}
```

the component using the custom validator in a model based approach:

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyFormComponent {
    constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = formBuilder.group({emailList: [[], requiredList]})
        …
```

or set it later with

```
this.form.controls.emailList.setValidators([requiredList]);
```

In the template use your custom component that can deal with lists as values

```
<email-list formControlName="emailList"></email-list>
```